# Why does my HTMLButton postback anyway, even with onclick return false set?

Tags: html, jquery, button, postback

I havea button on my page:

```
<button runat="server" id="btnRegister" class="button1" onserverclick="btnRegister_Click">Register</button>
```

I use jQuery for adding a client click event:

```
$("#btnRegister").click(function () { 
    return CheckUserData(); 
});

function CheckUserData(){
    return false;
}
```

When I press the button, the page does a postback! Why is it doing this?

Comment: Did you tried to declair your function before calling it? I mean just put function syntax code above of jquery.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was an JavaScript error in the CheckUserData() function. After correcting error, the page will never postback!

The right use is:

```
$("#btnRegister").click(function () { 
    if(!CheckUserData()) { 
        return false; 
    } 
});
```

Because on serverclick will add postback code after your click function.